# how do i get dynamic width of text entered in input control

Tags: actionscript-3

```
here i need the text width according to font size and font width of input text control and it should calculate the dynamic width of the entered text.  
i have tried with the following code but it is not getting updated for the text width.
```

for first time for any font size it will give proper text width.after reaching text width 350,i need to reduce the font size and at that time the text width is not getting updated.and vice-versa. 
  please share the answer for it.

```
  protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
                {
                    cmpTextLabel.inputComponent.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, handleInputComponentChange);
                }


    private function handleInputComponentChange(e:Event):void
                {
                    var tm:TextLineMetrics = cmpTextLabel.measureText(cmpTextLabel.text);

            var txtWidth:int =tm.width; 
                                    cmpTextLabel.maxWidth=cmpTextLabel.width;
                    cmpTextLabel.maxHeight=cmpTextLabel.height;

                    if(txtWidth>350)
                    {
                        var i:int=TemplateModel.getInstance().getFontSizeIndexFromDictionary(cmpTextLabel.compFontSize);

                        i=i-1;
                        if(i>=0)
                            cmpTextLabel.compFontSize=TemplateModel.getInstance().getFontSizeFromDictionary(i);
                        else
                            cmpTextLabel.compFontSize=TemplateModel.getInstance().getFontSizeFromDictionary(0);
                    }
                    if(txtWidth<350 && cmpTextLabel.compFontSize<24)
                    {
                        var j:int=TemplateModel.getInstance().getFontSizeIndexFromDictionary(cmpTextLabel.compFontSize);
                        j=j+1;
                        cmpTextLabel.compFontSize=TemplateModel.getInstance().getFontSizeFromDictionary(j);
                    } 

    <singlelinetext:CmpSLTruncateLabel id="cmpTextLabel"  skinClass="com.presentation.components.home.templates.comps.singlelinetext.SkinSLTruncateLabel"
                                  width="{dataModel.width}" height="{dataModel.height}" useHandCursor="false" buttonMode="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example inputComponent has width according to labelComponent's text width.

```
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

    [Bindable]
    private var tm:TextLineMetrics;

    private function labelComponent_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
        tm = labelComponent.measureText(labelComponent.text);
    }

    private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
        tm = labelComponent.measureText(labelComponent.text);
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:TextInput id="labelComponent"
                 text="Hello world"
                 fontSize="15" fontFamily="Arial"
                 change="labelComponent_changeHandler(event)"/>
    <s:TextInput id="inputComponent"
                 borderVisible="true"
                 width="{tm.width}" focusSkin="{null}"
                 contentBackgroundColor="0xffffff"
                 fontSize="15" fontFamily="Arial"/>
</s:HGroup>
```